# Proper way for asking to leave

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, politeness

I am about to take an assesment for responsible service of alcohol licence. There is a video question and I need to tell someone to leave in that video.

Once I saw a scene in The Simpsons and there was an expression like;

> Good evening sir. Would you please leave without a fuss, right now?

Is it common usage? Is using the *without a fuss* clause perceived as offensive?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a question of [English.se] and not related to **learning** English in anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Considering the context, if someone had too much to drink, I don't know that you would ask them to leave. If they drove home and something happened, you might be partially liable for (1) serving him enough to get him drunk; and (2) telling him to leave when he shouldn't have been driving.

There are many ways, formal or informal, to ask someone to leave. When it's more formal, it's more authoritative. Less formal is more friendly and sometimes a better approach when you're talking to someone who's drunk or upset.

The phrase from The Simpsons is fine. "Without a fuss" is not offensive at all. A more informal way might be:

> Please leave and don't make a scene.

You can also say:

> Leave now and don't cause any trouble on your way out.

> I'll get you a cab, because you're going home now.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the person telling the other person to leave expects the person to make a fuss when told to leave, because he has done so before maybe? Depends on the person if they perceive it as offensive I should think.